# Generating a Random Number between 1 and 10 Java

Tags: java, random

I want to generate a number between 1 and 10 in Java.

Here is what I tried:

```
Random rn = new Random();
int answer = rn.nextInt(10) + 1;
```

Is there a way to tell what to put in the parenthesis `()` when calling the nextInt method and what to add?

Comment: Did you read the documentation, which explains exactly how to use this function?

Comment: @SLaks I actually did, I was still confused after.

Comment: You can just put it in your code:
int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10 + 1);

Comment: If you wanna see the code check here - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Random.java

Comment: System.out.println( (int)(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min))
I use this to generate a random number between min and max inclusively

Comment: (int) Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)

Answer (score 316, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) says, this method call returns "a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)". This means that you will get numbers from 0 to 9 in your case. So you've done everything correctly by adding one to that number.

Generally speaking, if you need to generate numbers from `min` to `max` (including both), you write

```
random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
```

Comment: java.util.Random

Comment: see code here - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Random.java

Comment: `new Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min`

Comment: or use this:

System.out.println( (int)(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min))

Answer (score 101):

The standard way to do this is as follows:

Provide:

- min Minimum value
- max Maximum value

and get in return a Integer between min and max, inclusive.

```
Random rand = new Random();

// nextInt as provided by Random is exclusive of the top value so you need to add 1 

int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

See the relevant [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29).

As explained by Aurund, Random objects created within a short time of each other will tend to produce similar output, so it would be a good idea to keep the created Random object as a field, rather than in a method.

Comment: `Random rand = new Random();` I would go so far as to say that it must be a field.  `Random` objects created within a short time of each other will tend to produce similar output.  So many calls to `randInt` within a short period of time will not give evenly distributed output.

Answer (score 26):

This will work for generating a number 1 - 10. Make sure you import Random at the top of your code.

```
import java.util.Random;
```

If you want to test it out try something like this.

```
Random rn = new Random();

for(int i =0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int answer = rn.nextInt(10) + 1;
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Also if you change the number in parenthesis it will create a random number from 0 to that number -1 (unless you add one of course like you have then it will be from 1 to the number you've entered).

Comment: why is this i < 100 inside parenthesis of for? It should be 10

Comment: It will generate 100 numbers between 1-10

Comment: This answer mostly repeats the previous answers without providing a new alternative.