# Why does int answer = generator.nextInt(10) + 1; only produce numbers between 1 and 10?

Tags: java, random, iterator

I don't understand why it wouldn't generate upwards of 11.

Here is my tester code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class randomNumberTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Random rn = new Random();
         //tests random number generator (between 1(inc) and 10(excl))
         for(int i =0; i < 100; i++)
         {
             int answer = rn.nextInt(10) + 1;
             System.out.println(answer);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the method you're calling? The comment in your own code says that the upper bound is exclusive ("excl")... how would you expect to get an answer of 11 if `nextInt(10)` can only return a value up to 9, and you're adding 1 to that?

Comment: Yeah i realize now i made a stupid mistake. I did read it, but it didn't sink in for some reason. Sorry for the bad post.

Comment: you  follow this post it is already discuss http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java                                                                                                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389890/generating-a-random-number-between-1-and-10-java

Comment: @SeanM - if you consider it a bad post, you can always delete it using the link under the question. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome ahaha. I have a lot to learn! Unfortunately I can't delete it any more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the Javadoc. `rn.nextInt(10)` generates numbers from 0 to 9. Adding 1 gives you a range from 1 to 10.

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value **(exclusive)**