# Inserting a number between each letter of a word

Tags: java

I have a project which requires me to insert a random number (between 0 and 9) after each letter in a word, is there any way to do this simply?

```
System.out.println(sent.replaceAll(".(?!$)", "$0 "));
```

I can get a space between each letter with this code but I'm not sure how to insert the numbers randomly

```
Input = Table
Output would = T8a9b6l2e4
```

Comment: Could you give some examples of sample Input And Output. Without that, it's just pure guessing

Comment: if you have a space between each letter, you can replace them with a random number

Comment: Yes there is a way to do it easily, though probably not using a regex.  Regular expressions are not good at generating random digits.  Better to use some more standard Java code, where there is a class `Random` which can easily generate a random digit.

Comment: sent = sent.replaceFirst(" ", r); The problem is only this piece of code, Random cannot be converted to a string so how would I fix this (Netbeans)

Comment: @Hexed That error is fixed now. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
String sent="a b c d e f";
Random r=new Random();
while(sent.contains(" ")){
    int f= random.nextInt(9-0+1)+0;
    sent=sent.replaceFirst(" ",String.valueOf(f));
}
System.out.println(sent);
```

this should work and if not it might give you an idea on how to solve it

Code for random int from: [Generating a Random Number between 1 and 10 Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389890/generating-a-random-number-between-1-and-10-java)

Comment: Thanks, it says there's an error on r.next(); it requires an int

Comment: i updated my code a bit. only problem will be the r at the replacing. you will have to find something there

Comment: `sent=sent.replaceFirst(" ",r);`, You are converting a `Random` object to `String`

Comment: i know. i already said that there will be an error. i have now updated it. only thing to do is to limit the range of the ints generated

Comment: Is there a space between each letter? Otherwise the easiest and fastest would be to just iterate through the whole thing and create a new string with letters from the input and digits from your random thingie.

Comment: i found this code smoother. might be that you are right. yes there are spaces between each letter, because op was able to insert a space between each letter

Comment: Haha, I see what you mean. Then it makes sense if you put it that way, but it does make the space insertion thing a bit redundant. I like the replaceFirst() idea :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. Yeah, and I have a question for another task. Can anyone help me write a code to determine if the inputted number is an ordered number (if the first half of the number minus the second half = 1 e.g. 123122; 123-122 = 1) and to also find out if the ordered number is an ordered square (An ordered square is an ordered number that is a perfect square e.g. 8281)

Comment: write a new question for this and try to make it more clear. i as a non Englishmen don't understand what your question is. maybe other do

Comment: @Hexed Also do some research before asking, or else your question would be closed as a **HomeWork question**

Comment: as an English speaker I don't understand it, I have done research. Can't find anything.I can only post a question every 90 minutes. So: If a first half of a number minus the second half of the number = 1 it is an Ordered number. If the same number has an Integer square root it is an Ordered Square. E.g. 8281 is an ordered number and square. I have attempted a code to allow a user to input a number and the number is checked to see if it an Ordered square and prime and then prints out if the number is an Ordered number and an Ordered square if it is a square

Comment: then wait the 90 minutes and write a full question about it with your code shown and so on. that will make it much easier to help you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. Not perfect/optimized but should do the job.

```
    final int min = 0;
    final int max = 9;
    final String inputString= "testingThisString";
    String str = "";
    final Random random = new Random();
    for(final char c: inputString.toCharArray()){
        final int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
        str += c + "" + String.valueOf(randomNumber);
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: This! Clear and straightforward

Answer (score 1):

A `Stream` might be useful in this case:

```
final Random rand = new Random();
String str = "string";
str = Stream.of(str.split("")).map(
             x -> x + Integer.valueOf(rand.nextInt(10))
      ).collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(str); // s8t9r6i0n1g6
```

We get a stream of individual letters in the string, and add a random number to each string. Finally we join everything together to get a final string.

A small update. Since java-8 `String` class has `chars` methods which returns a stream of character. So we can use it directly without splitting the original string. For example:

```
Random rand = new Random();
String str = "string";
str = str.chars().mapToObj(
          c -> String.valueOf((char)c) + rand.nextInt(10)
      ).collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(str); // s5t7r8i4n3g1
```