# Simple Magic 8-Ball Java Program Problems

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to write a program for a Magic 8-ball program in Java. I need to use math.Random() to generate responses, use a while loop to take questions and get responses, then log the questions and predictions into a .txt file.

I have everything that I wrote here, though I can't seem to quite figure out why the random number generator is generating the same number over and over again. It does generate one, but what I need is something that will generate multiple random numbers. Also, my printwriter isn't logging the questions into the .txt file.

```
public class Magic8Ball {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean questionAsked = false;


    String question = "Please ask a question and make sure to add a ? (X to quit):";
    String response = getPrediction();
    String filename = "src/predictions.txt";
    String sentinel =  "x";
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    //variables needed        

    PrintWriter out = null;
    //Printwriter
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(filename);
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //try-catch statement

    while (!questionAsked) {

        System.out.println(question);
        String input = scnr.nextLine();
        out.println(input);
        //Log questions

        if (input.contains("?")) {

            System.out.println(response);
            out.println(response);
            //Log predictions
        }

        else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(sentinel)) {
            questionAsked = true;
            System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Please try again.");
        }

    }
    //Main process (Ask questions and get predictions)

}

public static String getPrediction () {
    //getPrediction() method for the predictions

    int randomNum = (int) (Math.random()* 10) + 1;
    //Get a random number
    /*Error: Keeps the same number for all the responses until you
    restart the program. Need to figure out how to make it restart 
    right away.
    */

    String response[] = new String[10];

    response[0] = "It is certain";
    response[1] = "As I see it, yes";
    response[2] = "Reply hazy try again";
    response[3] = "Don't count on it";
    response[4] = "Without a doubt";
    response[5] = "Cannot predict now";
    response[6] = "Ask again later";
    response[7] = "Very doubtful";
    response[8] = "Signs point to yes";
    response[9] = "You may rely on it";
   //List of responses

    String answer = response[randomNum];

    return answer;
    //Returns a string from the array to the main method
}
```

}

Comment: As per the answer in the duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20389922/2310289  Move the Random to be a field, not a variable

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you for responding for the random numbers! I was wondering if this can be opened again as I still have a problem with the printwriter.

Comment: I guess that the `src` directory does not exist below your classpath